# What does for(;1;) mean in the C language?

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop

What does `for(;1;)` mean in C?

Is it the same as `for(;;)` in the sense of an infinite loop?

I know that the position where `1` is typed is the condition part of the variable, but in this `for` loop, I'm not convinced that it is indeed an infinite loop.

Comment: its loops like that until that 1 becomes a 0 :)

Comment: It means `while (1)`, i.e., "run forever". The only way to exit this loop is with a `break` or a `return` statement somewhere inside it. In C++, `throw`ing an exception is another option.

Comment: then why did the programmer who coded this source use ' for(;1;)-loop'? for(;;)-loop is much brief than the for(;1;)-loop.

Comment: Perhaps he or she realized that `for(;;)` would be a little obscure to other people reading their code. Readability is important, you know. Try to stick to it when possible.

Comment: He tossed a coin. "Heads means for(;;) and tails means for(;1;)" - he said. Infinite loop can be written in like 1000 different ways. This is simply one of them.

Comment: I'd opt for `while(true)`. That doesn't leave much to interpretation.

Comment: @barakmanos Heh, for me, `for(;;)` is actually almost the canonical "forever" loop. `for (; 1 ; )` is *less* readable for me. Always depends on your team, I guess.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Wouldn't work in C, unless you define `true`.

Comment: BTW, as much as this question looks silly to most of us, it makes sense for newbies to ask it, so I see no reason to downvote it (except, perhaps, the fact that OP could have searched for some description of the `for` keyword, but I doubt that he or she would have found an answer to the specific question at hand).

Comment: @barakmanos The question was tagged C++, and I'd expect it would be easy to figure out how to transform the code into valid C.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Was tagged both C and C+, and now I see that the C++ tag has been removed.

Answer (score 7):

According to the C Standard (6.8.5.3 The for statement)

> 2 Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. **An omitted
>   expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.**

So in fact you yourself instead of the compiler replaced the omitted expression-2 by nonzero constant 1.

So these two statements

```
for(;1;) { /*...*/ }
```

and

```
for(;;) { /*...*/ }
```

are fully equivalent.

In  my opinion it is much better to write

```
while ( 1 ) { /*...*/ }
```

instead of the shown above for statements.

Comment: @Lundin I do not have a talant to write so long posts as you have.:)

Answer (score 3):

Be convinced. For loop works until the condition-part of the expression becomes false. And in `C` 1 means "`true`", which - obviously - will never become false.

Comment: then is for(;2;)-loop right sentence for infinite loop? what about for(;0;) and for(;-1;)?

Comment: @coke you ought to be able to answer those yourself. Why not try?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Your both expressions for(;1;) and for(;;) will give you infinite loop.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) says

> All of the expressions of the for statement are optional; for example,
>   the following statement is used to write an infinite loop:

```
for (; ; )
{
    // ...
}
```

So no criteria in condition of loop will give you a infinite loop.

On you other question for(;1;): you are not convinced that it will give you infinite loop.

It has to a infinite loop, Because result of condition statement is not equal to 0.

Following are some examples:

```
 for(;1;)   //Infinite loop
 for(;0;)       //Loop will not execute at all
 for(;-1;)       //Infinite loop.
```

Comment: What does a "Single condition loop" mean?